# Angularjs $http my second then before first then is done.

Tags: angularjs, promise

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, but the Report.xls gets downloaded before report.students gets updated.
How can I make it wait for report.students to be updated before Report.xls get downloaded?

Here is my code

`data service function

```
function getStudentsForExcel() {

        var filter = studentFilter;

        filter.data.perPage = StudentsModel.data.countTotal;
        return $http.post(url + "/summeries", filter.data)
                    .then(onStudentSummeries)
                .catch(onError);

        function onStudentSummeries(response) {

            return response.data;

        }
    }`
```

This function in my controller
`

```
function tocsv() {
       studentData.getStudentsForExcel().then(function(data) {
           report.students = data;





       }).then(function() {
           var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('tableReport').innerHTML], {
               type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"
           });
           saveAs(blob, "Report.xls");
        });



    }`
```

Comment: can't you use one single then() ?

Comment: Well, I'd prefer creating a new `$q` promise inside the service and return it, and on the `then` of the `$http` inside the service, simply resolve it.

Comment: I tried using one then()

Comment: I don't see anu usage of `$q` in your code. Would be nice if you could provide more code or jsfiddle link

Comment: Can you see your `onError` function?

Comment: All I am doing  in error function is log to the console function onError() {
            console.log("Something went wrong");
        }